# How to make the parallel port to work?

Tags: permissions, configuration, parallel-port

Trying to make a cheap CNC machine to work, I have to connect through a parallel port. Unfortunately, I do not manage to make the parallel port to work.

It seem the PCI parallel port card is detected, but I do not achieve to transmit/connect anything to it.

**How to make the parallel port working?**

**How to make the parallel port working with normal user privileges?**

> EDITED
>   The port seem to works only under root privileges. 
>   That is probably the issue. 
>   But how to make the parallel port to work for normal users?

.

> Note: My machine is a Debian Linux with RT kernel 4.9.

---

**What I did tried:**

The PCI parallel card is plugged into my computer.

Running $`lsmod |grep ppdev` return what seem a correct result:

```
ppdev                  20480  2 
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
```

Running $`lspci -v` Return information, that I don't fully understand:

```
03:01.0 Parallel controller: MosChip Semiconductor Technology Ltd. PCI 9865 Multi-I/O Controller (prog-if 03 [IEEE1284])
    Subsystem: Device a000:2000
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 22
    I/O ports at dc00 [size=8]
    I/O ports at d880 [size=8]
    Memory at fcfff000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at fcffe000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: parport_pc
```

And more data: $`dmesg |grep parport` (note: I have on single parallel port) return

```
[   11.791907] parport_pc 00:02: reported by Plug and Play ACPI
[   11.791998] parport0: PC-style at 0x378 (0x778), irq 5 [PCSPP,TRISTATE,EPP]
[   11.888153] lp0: using parport0 (interrupt-driven).
[   11.888949] parport1: PC-style at 0xdc00, irq 22 [PCSPP,TRISTATE,EPP]
[   11.984195] lp1: using parport1 (interrupt-driven).
```

I downloaded a test application from [here](http://wiki.linuxcnc.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Parallel_Port_Tester), which I run from the command line WITHOUT root permissions. It shows all the out-pins in red and all the in-pins in green. When pressing on an out-pin, it switch to green, but I suspect it does not mean anything.

[image: PortTest script with Pin01 pressed]

Finally, the ultimate test: I connected to the parallel port a LED between `GND` and `PIN_02` (with 1k ohm resistor). If I connect it to `BUZY` (by default on), the led turn on, but while connected to `PIN_01`, it never light, even while pressing the button from the test application.

[image: Led test]

From all those test, I suspect the card is correctly installed, but due to some permission or other misconfiguration, it does not work.

I tried to run the PortTest with root admin, but it seem not happy with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the privileges of the parallel port: by default, it is accessible only by users of the group `lp`. The `root` user is obviously allowed to it, but normal users are not.

Adding the user to the `lp` group make the parallel port accessible without sudo:

```
adduser <user-name> lp
```

After that, the parallel port is working and I could continue the configuration.